# I am getting below error while using ui-grid in angular js

Tags: angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module("finApp", ["ui.grid"]);
app.controller(
  "finController",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("url", "data")
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;

      }, function(errorResponse) {});
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

While executing above code I am getting below error:

> angular.min.js:122 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>               at new  (ui-grid.js:3330)
>               at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:43)
>               at Q.instance (angular.min.js:93)

Comment: Maybe in your response, "data" is not present. Check your response. do console.log of your response data

Comment: Added Snippet with the best I can guess versions of the libraries referenced in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `$scope.gridOptions = {}` before the http request

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

on success response from the API just `concat` the response data into the `gridData` array. As `gridData` is assigned back to the  `$scope.gridOptions.data` only.

```
--------
JS file 
--------

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'gridData',
    ..........,
    ..........,
    ..........
}

$scope.gridData = [];

$scope.gridData = $scope.gridData.concat(response.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check response by log or alert

or Define grids column like below to test whether your ui-grid is working or not:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    paginationPageSizes: [10, 20, 50],
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    columnDefs: [

    {
        width: '10%',
        field: 'lastname',
        displayName: 'Last Name'
    },

    {
        width: '25%',
        field: 'firstname',
        displayName: 'First Name'
    },
     {
         width: '8%',
         field: 'Status',
         displayName: 'Status'
     },
    {
        width: '6%',
        field: "actions",
        displayName: "Actions",
        cellTemplate: '<a href="#" title="test"  class="Icon"></a>'
    }
    ]
};
```

And in JS

```
var app = angular.module("finApp", ["ui.grid"]);
    app.controller(
            "finController",
            function($scope,$http){
                $http.get("url","data")
                    .then(function(response) {
                        $scope.gridOptions.data =response.data;

                },function(errorResponse) {
       });
    });
```

Refer this: [UI GRID](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro)